# validate form before posting to controller. Then redirect to another action. (jquery validation plugin)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I would like to validate my form before it posts to my controller and then redirect to another action. I need help because I am in no way familiar with the syntax to do this. The application currently validates but automatically redirects to "/Rxcard/Search". I only need it to redirect once it has passed validation.

form:

```
@model RxCard.Models.AccountDetail
<div class="details-full" style="left: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <div class="page">
        <div>
            @Html.Partial("_Nav")
        </div>
        <section class=" main-content acct-list">
            <form id="Fields" method="post">
                <label typeof="label">ADD NEW CLINIC</label>

                <input id="chkIsActive" type="hidden" name="chkIsActive" value="@Model.Pharmacy.IsActive" @(Model.Pharmacy.IsActive == "true" ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
                <input type="hidden" name="AccountID" id="AccountID" value="@Model.Pharmacy.AccountID" />

                <div class="fieldcontainer">
                    <label>Clinic Name</label>
                    <input id="editAccountName" name="editAccountName" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.AccountName" />
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontainer">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input id="editAddress" name="editAddress" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Address" />
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontainer">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input id="editCity" name="editCity" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.City" />
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontainer">
                    <label>State</label>
                    <input id="editState" name="editState" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.State" />
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontainer">
                    <label>Zip</label>
                    <input id="editZip" name="editZip" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.ZipCode" />
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontainer">
                    <label>Phone Number (optional)</label>
                    <input id="editArea" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editArea" style="float:left; width:60px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Area" depends />
                    <input id="editPrefix" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editSuffix')" name="editPrefix" style="float:left; width:60px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Prefix" depends />
                    <input id="editSuffix" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editSuffix" style="float:left; width:60px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Suffix" depends />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="cancelAccount" name="cancelAccount" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/rxcard/search'" />
                    <input id="saveAccount" name="saveAccount" type="submit" value="Save" />
                </div>

            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

validation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Fields").validate({
        errorElem: 'div',
        rules: {
            editAccountName: {
                required: true
            },
            editAddress: {
                required: true
            },
            editCity: {
                required: true
            },
            editState: {
                required: true,
                stateregex: /^([^0-9]*)$/,
                maxlength: 2
            },
            editZip: {
                required: true,
                zipregex: /^([^A-Za-z]*)$/,
            },
            editArea: {
                required: false,
                minlength: 3,
                digits: true
            },
            editPrefix: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return $("#editArea").val() != "";
                },
                minlength: 3,
                digits: true
            },
            editSuffix: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return $("#editPrefix").val() != "";
                },
                digits: true,
                minlength: 4
            }

        },
        messages: {
            editAccountName: {
                required: "Enter the account name."

            },
            editAddress: {
                required: "Enter the address."
            },
            editCity: {
                required: "Enter a City."
            },
            editState: {
                required: "Enter a State.",
                maxlength: "Enter only two characters",
            },
            editZip: {
                required: "Enter a zip code"
            },
            editArea: {
                required: "Please enter a complete area code",
                minlength: "Please enter 3 digits for the area code",
                digits: "Phone number must only contain numbers"
            },
            editPrefix: {
                required: "Please enter a complete prefix",
                minlength: "Please enter 3 digits for the prefix",
                digits: "Phone number must only contain numbers"
            },
            editSuffix: {
                required: "Please enter a complete suffix",
                minlength: "Please enter valid 10 digit phone number",
                digits: "Phone number must only contain numbers"
            }

        }

    })

    $("#saveAccount").click(function (e) {

            $.post("/RxCard/SaveAccount",
           {
               IsActive: true,
               AccountId: $("#AccountID").val(),
               AccountName: $("#editAccountName").val(),
               Address: $("#editAddress").val(),
               City: $("#editCity").val(),
               State: $("#editState").val(),
               ZipCode: $("#editZip").val(),
               Area: $("#editArea").val(),
               Prefix: $("#editPrefix").val(),
               Suffix: $("#editSuffix").val()
           });

        window.location.href = "/RxCard/Search";
    });



    //validators for regular expressions
    $.validator.addMethod("stateregex", function (value, element, regexpr) {
        return regexpr.test(value);
    }, "State must contain no numbers.");
    $.validator.addMethod("zipregex", function (value, element, regexpr) {
        return regexpr.test(value);
    }, "State must contain only numbers.");
});
```

controller:

```
[ValidateRequest]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveAccount(string AccountId,string IsActive,string AccountName, string Address, string City, string State, string ZipCode, int Area, int Prefix, int Suffix)
        {
            var isactive = Convert.ToBoolean(IsActive) ? 1 : 0;
            var PhoneNumber = Area.ToString() + Prefix.ToString() + Suffix.ToString();


            using (OdbcConnection _conn = new OdbcConnection("FILEDSN=c:\\datasources\\RxCard.dsn"))
            using (OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand())
            {
                cmd1.Connection = _conn;
                cmd1.CommandText = "{call web.Maint_UpdateClinic(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", AccountId);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isactive);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", AccountName);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountAddress", Address);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", ZipCode);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaCode", Area);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WebID", CookieStore.GetCookie("WebId"));

                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _conn.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _conn.Close();
            }
            //Response.Redirect("~/rxcard/search");
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Why in the world are you not using a model, applying validation attributes to the model properties, strongly binding to you model using the `HtmlHelper` methods, and posting back the model. You writing twice as much code as necessary in order to ensure you never get correct model binding or validation. I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

First up all i am not getting this line

```
   window.location.href = "/RxCard/Search";
```

why you are trying to redirect like this in saveAccount.

define your form like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccount", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmFields", @autocomplete = "off" }))
{}
```

Then remove the submit button from form and take it as normal button outside of the form and write the click event in jquery

In Click event forcefully validate the form its true then redirect to your method 
e.g try like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnSaveAccount', function (e) {
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#frmFields'));
var $valid = $("#frmFields").valid();
if (!$valid) {
      $validator.focusInvalid();
       return false;
  }
 else {
      SaveAccount();
      return true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make sure that the form is valid or not using the following code.

```
  $("#saveAccount").click(function (e) {

  var isValid = $('nameOfYourForm').valid();

    if(isValid) {

            $.post("/RxCard/SaveAccount",
       {
           IsActive: true,
           AccountId: $("#AccountID").val(),
           AccountName: $("#editAccountName").val(),
           Address: $("#editAddress").val(),
           City: $("#editCity").val(),
           State: $("#editState").val(),
           ZipCode: $("#editZip").val(),
           Area: $("#editArea").val(),
           Prefix: $("#editPrefix").val(),
           Suffix: $("#editSuffix").val()
       });

    window.location.href = "/RxCard/Search";
   }


});
```